# GQL Query in AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore, gql

Im working with the dataStore trying to perfom a simple query, but it doesnt work as supposed to:

```
class User_Machine(db.Model):
    machine_id = db.IntegerProperty (required = True)
    username = db.StringProperty (required = True)
    last_call = db.DateTimeProperty (auto_now = True)

def query(username, machine_id)
    q = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM User_Machine WHERE username=:1 AND machine_id=:2', username, machine_id)
    r = q.get()
    return r

print query('uherran', 23)
```

And my response is:

> None

And I was expecting to read this record:

The values in the datastopre viewer are:

```
Enitty Kind  User_Machine
Entity Key   ahBkZXZ-Z2VzdG9yYXZpc29zchILEgxVc2VyX01hY2hpbmUYKAw
ID   40
username (string)   uherran
last_call (datetime)    2012-08-19 09:57:35
machine_id (long)       23
```

There must be something completely wrong in my understanding on how querys go.

Anyone can help?

Thanks.

In fact. I adapted a little but my code to provide clarity, but it seems I didnt make a propper error check.

The code is:

```
def check_machine_username(self, machine_id, username):
        key='CHECK_MACHINE_USERNAME_'+machine_id+'_'+username
        q= memcache.get(key)
        if q:
            return True
        else:
            logging.info(username)
            logging.info(machine_id)
            q = dbstructure.User_Machine.all()
            q.filter('username = ', username)
            q.filter('machine_id = ', machine_id)

            if q.get():
                loggin.info('query right')
                memcache.set(key,True)
                return True
            else:
                logging.info('query wrong')
                return False
```

No matter what I have in my User_machine db that query always returns empty.

Comment: As @GuidoVanRossum says, you may be passing a string as your `machine_id`, especially if there is no error when you define `key` in `check_machine_username` (since it should be trying to concatenate a string and an integer, which would fail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that in the failing case your machine_id is a string, whereas it should be an int.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I just notice it and was trying to update my question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem as I notice it, was that `machine_id` was an integer and I was using a string.

```
q.filter('username = ', username)
q.filter('machine_id = ', int(machine_id))
                          ^^^
```

Its the bad thing about asuming a type.

Thanks to every one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is because you aren't returning the value of the function back to your `print` (I may or may not do this all the time as well :) ). Try this:

```
def query(username, machine_id)
    q = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM User_Machine WHERE username=:1 AND machine_id=:2', username, machine_id)
    r = q.get()
    return r # or just return q.get()
```

Note that this will return a `User_Machine` object (and not a formatted dictionary/other response like you may be expecting) which you'll then need to handle (e.g. instead of `print`, assign it to a `result` variable and then you can access its attributes by doing `result.machine_id`, etc.).

You can also use a Query object to accomplish the same thing:

```
def query(username, machine_id)
    # Same as using SELECT * in the Gql query above)
    q = User_Machine.all()

    # Then apply the filters (you can also do q.filter(..).filter(..))
    q.filter('username = ', username)
    q.filter('machine_id = ', machine_id)
    return q.get()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It seems I made a typo in when I was doing my question. I made some clarifications in the answer.